# Teradata - how to select without locking writers? (LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS vs. LOCKING TABLE FOR ACCESS)

Tags: teradata, rowlocking, table-locking

I am developing an application which fetches some data from a Teradata DWH. DWH developers told me to use `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` before all `SELECT` queries to avoid delaying writes to that table(s).

Being very familiar with MS SQL Servers's `WITH(NOLOCK)` hint, I see `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` as its equivalent. However, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements do not allow using `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` (it is not clear for me why this fails, since it should apply for table(s) the statement selects from, not to the one I insert into):

```
-- this works
LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS 
SELECT Cols
FROM Table

-- this does not work
LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS 
INSERT INTO SomeVolatile
SELECT Cols
FROM PersistentTable
```

I have seen that `LOCKING TABLE ... FOR ACCESS` can be used, but it is unclear if it fits my need (`NOLOCK` equivalent - do not block writes).

**Question:** **What hint should I use to minimize writes delaying when selecting within an `INSERT` statement?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` on an INSERT-SELECT statement. The INSERT statement will put a WRITE lock on the table to which it's writing and a READ lock on the tables from which it's selecting.

If it's absolutely imperative that you get `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` on the INSERT-SELECT, then consider creating a view like:

```
 CREATE VIEW tmpView_PersistentTable AS
 LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS
 SELECT Cols FROM PersistentTable;
```

And then perform your INSERT-SELECT from the view:

```
 INSERT INTO SomeVolatile
 SELECT Cols FROM tmpView_PersistentTable;
```

Comment: Using views is a good advice. Unfortunately, I am not allow to perform changes, but I can ask MDW developers to wrap the tables I am accessing into "lock row for access" views.

Comment: @Alexei: In a Teradata environment most end users only got access to 1:1 views including LOCK ROW ACCESS, thus those views might already exist. Additionally, unless you Select using the PI of the source table there's no difference between LOCK ROW/TABLE. Btw, MDW = a big retailer from Germany?

Comment: @dnoeth - oh, sorry. MDW = master data warehouse. I have seen it used as an acronym in several local companies and I thought it is a known acronym, but you and Google proved me wrong. And yes, it's about a big retailer from DE's data warehouse.

Comment: @dnoeth - about the views, I will check with warehouse devs. The tables I am working contain metadata information about installations, ETL objects tables/view etc. and are not used by any normal user. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei: The **M** in *MDW* is not **Master**, it's the company name :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but it's always been my understanding that this is one of the reasons your users/applications/etc should access data through views.  Views lock `for access`, which does not prevent inserts/updates.  Selecting from a table uses read locks, which will prevent inserts/updates.

The downside is with access locks, the possibility for dirty reads exists.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below and you should be good.

```
LOCKING TABLE PersistentTable FOR ACCESS 
INSERT INTO SomeVolatile
SELECT Cols
FROM PersistentTable ;
```